# Angular2: custom component inside inside p-dataTable

Tags: angular

I use primefaces/angular2 in one of my projects,
I'd like to create a listing component that wraps their p-dataTable component and provides data to it.

I created a very simple component like this :

```
<p-dataTable [value]="data">
        <!--<ng-content></ng-content>-->
        <app-listing-column title="test"></app-listing-column>
        <p-column [header]="'title'">
            <template pTemplate="body">
                test
            </template>
        </p-column>
        <p-column *ngFor="let col of columns" [field]="col.key" [header]="col.title"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

I also created another component (app-listing-column) that wraps their column like this :

```
<p-column [header]="'title'">
    <template pTemplate="body">
        test
    </template>
</p-column>
```

The columns from ngFor are displayed properly but the (app-listing-column) doesn't add a new column with template to the displayed columns

**What I exactly want is to add a custom component *that wraps p-column* inside the p-dataTable component**

** I added html only as there's no logic associated with the component

Comment: revise your post to make it meaningful

Comment: Can you tell me what isn't clear so I can make it more meaningful?

Comment: the recently edited point makes sense. Read the post without that line and analyse